# Trying to print 3 types of time: universal, standard, and military (3 files)

Tags: c++, class, function, constructor

```
 #ifndef time_time_h

 #define time_time_h

class time

{

public:

time();
void settime(int h, int m, int s);
void printuniversal();
void printmilitary();
void printstandard();

private:

int hour;
int minute;
int second;
};



 #endif

  //////////////////.hfile////////////////


 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "time.h"

time::time()

{

int h, m, s;

hour=0;
minute=0;
second=0;

hour=h;
minute=m;
second=s;


}

void time::settime(int h, int m, int s)

{

if (h<=0||h>23||h==99)

{

    h=0;

}

if (m<=0||m>59||m==99)
{
    m=0;

}

if (s<=0||s>59||s==99)
{
    s=0;
}
}

void time::printuniversal()

{

if (hour<10)
{
cout<<"0"<<hour<<":";
}
else
    cout<<hour<<":";

if (minute<10)
{
cout<<"0"<<minute<<":";
}
else
    cout<<minute<<":";
if (second<10)
{
cout<<"0"<<second<<"\n";
}
else
    cout<<second<<"\n";

}

void time::printmilitary()

{

if (hour<10)
{
    cout<<"0"<<hour<<":";
}
else
    cout<<hour<<":";
if (minute<10)
{
    cout<<"0"<<minute<<"\n";
}
else
    cout<<minute<<"\n";
}


void time::printstandard()

{

if (hour>12)
{
    hour=hour-12;
    cout<<hour<<":";        
}
else if(hour<10)
{
    cout<<"0"<<minute<<":";
}

else
{
    cout<<hour<<":";
}

if(minute<10)
{
cout<<"0"<<minute<<":";
}

else
{
    cout<<minute<<":";
}

if(second<10)
{
    cout<<"0"<<second;
}

else
{
    cout<<second;
}

if (hour>12)
{
    cout<<" PM\n";
}

else
{
    cout<<"AM\n";
}
}
////////////////////cpp file//////////////


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "time.h"


int main()

{

int h, m, s;

time::time test;
test.settime(0,0,0);
test.printstandard();
test.printmilitary();
test.printuniversal();

time::time test2;
test2.settime(23, 4, 8);
test2.printstandard();
test2.printmilitary();
test2.printuniversal();

time::time test3;
test3.settime(99, 99, 99);
test3.printstandard();
test3.printmilitary();
test3.printuniversal();

cout<<"Enter hour, minutes, seconds:\n";
cin>>h>>m>>s;
time::time user;
user.settime(h, m, s);
user.printstandard();
user.printmilitary();
user.printuniversal();

return 0;
}
////////////main/////////////////////
```

It is supposed to output with settime (0,0,0), settime(23,4,8), and settime(99,99,99).
Giving: 00:00:00AM
00:00
00:00:00
11:04:08AM
23:04
23:04:08
00:00:00AM
00:00
00:00:00
"Enter hour, minute, seconds"

However, I get some ridiculous numbers:
32755:2074578800:01 PM
32755:2074578800
32755:2074578800:01
32755:2074578800:01 PM
32755:2074578800
32755:2074578800:01

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Your settime function does not set anything. It just tests for valid values and sets the variables to zero in case of invalid values.

You get the strange outputs because in the constructor you are declaring variables use them without initialising them.

This should work:

```
time::time()
{
    hour=0;
    minute=0;
    second=0;
}

void time::settime(int h, int m, int s)
{
    if (h<=0||h>23||h==99)
    {
        h=0;
    }

    if (m<=0||m>59||m==99)
    {
        m=0;
    }

    if (s<=0||s>59||s==99)
    {
        s=0;
    }
    hour = h;
    minute = m;
    second = s;
}
```

Comment: Use the *ctor-initializer-list* instead of assignment statements in the constructor.  But I do think you've spotted the problems.  +1

Comment: I have another small problem with the output of AM and PM inside printstandard(), any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, I just created another integer and now it all works. I've been working too long. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.